# XCode needs to be installed every time to detect iOS devices! Why? Any Solution?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, macos

XCode needs to be installed on every start up to detect iOS devices. Otherwise devices didn't  get detect. Why is it so? What to do? Any solutions?

Comment: Any screenshot, error message?

Comment: 'no provisioned iOS device detected

Answer (score 0):

You will have to register the UDID of every iOS device used for development, in the provisioning profile provided in apple developer account.

After registering the device, download the provisioning profile and add to your device.

Comment: but the same device is detecting on another system... in my system I need to re install the xcode to detect it... but it's detecting... needs to install xcode again and again...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new user on the system to see if it has the same issue?  Perhaps there is a bad preference file somewhere.

Comment: device get detected whenever I reinstall XCode. But device won't get detected after shut down! Then I again need to install XCode.

Comment: Is the same true if you create a new user and log in as that user instead of yourself?

Comment: Sorry, was hoping it was user specific... out of ideas. Try posting on the Apple developer forums too, there's an XCode 4 specific section.